# Upload to Google Drive use C#

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I have a problem. I use C# .Net 2013 Windows Form Application. I want to upload to Google Drive the file of the user selected.(The user cannot have a gmail account.) The project can work in any copmuter as .exe. However, the project wants to login in each case when I try. When I logged in, the project wants to allow from me. I don't want to this. Users will select the files they want to send and after that they will click on the send button. Users should not see any question. The selected file should be sent automatically. How can I do this?

Thanks for your help. Emrah.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want end users to upload files to a single Google Drive account. In that case you should probably look into using a [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/service-accounts), which allows the application to have it's own account without prompting the user for authorization.